# Directory structore of PHP/HTML project for CMS

Tags: php, html, web

I have my web page set up right. I am just starting to build a PHP section that will allow some CMS functions. The structure of my workspace is:

```
/workspace/website/index.html
/workspace/website/images
/workspace/website/admin/user_login.php
```

Now my `index.html` draws all of the images correctly. However my `user_login.php` does not. I have HTML wrapped around the PHP scripts with this link

```
    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/banner.png" height="100px" align="left" /></a>
```

When I put the `user_login.php` in the root directory everything shows up fine, but when I put it in the folder for my admin section none of the HTML stuff shows up.

What am I missing? Is this just really bad form for building a CMS section? I am trying to compartmentalize it as much as I can for organizational purposes but this is my first PHP/HTML work so I'm not too familiar with proper "form".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is change your image references to be absolute links, by adding an initial slash to the path:

```
<img src="/images/banner.png" height="100px" align="left" />
```

at the moment you have relative paths, so the browser is looking for the image at /admin/images/banner.png which obviously doesn't work.

This is a good habit to get into for any in-site links or references.

Comment: There's my "duh" moment! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Prepend `/` to your assets URL's to load them from the root, If you don't do so the browser tries to look for `admin/images/banner.png`.

Example:

```
<img src="/images/banner.png" height="100px" align="left" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths are relative to your current location. It is not just your images that will break, but any links or imports that use relative links.

When you are in admin/user_login.php, in other words, the browser is looking for

```
 <a href="admin/index.html"><img src="admin/images/banner.png" /></a>
```

You can get around this problem by setting up *root relative* links, i.e. paths that are based on the web root of the site.

```
 <a href="/index.html"><img src="/images/banner.png" /></a>
```